# EOFException when connecting to local Postgres in DBeaver

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dbeaver

I'm having troubles when trying to connect to local docker postgres db. I have spun up a new postgres db container on port 5434 which I can confirm is successfully running. I have added the docker ps command response below. For some reason when trying to connect to the new 5434 port though on DbBeaver I just get the following error
EOFException. I've also attached image of that below.

Don't really understand what is happening, as I'm certain I'm putting in correct auth details, and I have tried multiple times on other ports, but only connection to 5432 works. Anyone know how to get another port working?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That the container is running doesn't necessarily mean the database is.  What do you see in the db server's log file?

Comment: Do you have a wrong port mapping in your conf file? (5434:5434 leads to this error; it should be 5434:5432)

Answer (score 3):

I faced with the same issue and my port was as `5431:5431` since I was using different postgre server on `5432:5432` port. However I resolved this problem by changing my port as `5431:5432`. You probably had the same port problem.

Comment: thank you, it also works for me, but do you know why is it so?